# If point A to B, potential is 1.61V and point A to G, potential is 3.3V. So potential B to G should be 0V or 1.69V?

Tags: multimeter, voltage-measurement, ohms-law, nrf52832

I have this module : https://www.adafruit.com/product/3406

I was checking potential at different pin, I find something I don't know reason for.

While checking through multimeter I found potential from **3V pin to DFU pin shows 1.61V**, and 3V pin to GND Pin is 3.3V so doesn't that mean **DFU pin has a potential of 1.69V** (3.3V-1.61V) itself?

But **DFU Pin to GND** shows *0V* on multimeter. Could someone please tell me the reason for it?

Comment: The voltage on the pins might not be independent of loading them with a meter. Measure DFU to other voltages, and see what happens. What does DFU stand for anyway, that might give a clue.

Comment: @Neil_UK Its just 3.3V available on  board, DFU stands for Device Firmware Update

Comment: From your observations, and knowing the input impedance of your meter, you can calculate the effective impedance internally in series with the DFU pin. That is what your measurements are telling you.